# Can I write a CD using BD-RE drive

Tags: burning, blu-ray, cd-burning, cd-drive

I want to write audio songs on a recordable CD. Can I do that using a **BD-RE** type of Drive?

Comment: Please do some research before asking. 1) Have a look at your drive specifications. 2) Any program that can burn CDs. There are plenty – choose whatever you prefer. Software recommendation questions are considered off topic here.

Comment: @slhck: I have searched on the internet and I found that BD-RE stands for `Bluray Drive-Read Erase`. But I am confused whether it can be used to burn a CD. Most of the information about burning CD talks about a drive type with specs CD-RW so i don't know if BD-RE can be used to burn a CD or not.

Comment: Like I said, have you looked at the specs of your drive? That's why I asked. You also haven't mentioned the drive you're using in your question. I'd remove the second part of your question, which makes it off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can burn CDs with any drive that can burn DVD and Blu-ray discs.

Look at the drive's specifications: does it say that you can burn CD-R or CD-RWs with it? Then you're good.

Comment: The name of my drive is `BD-RE` and if I right click on it and go to properties then, under the Hardware tab, I see `DVD/CD-ROM drives` is written.

Comment: Don't look at the name of your drive in your operating system, but look up its specifications from the vendor. I'm sure your drive has some vendor and model name / number.

Comment: I don't have a specs manual. I can see `Matshita BD-MLT UJ272 SCSI CdRom Device` as name of the drive, which is probably the vendors name.

Comment: The Internet is great to look up specs! There, I googled it for you: http://burners.burn4free.com/matsushita-matshita-panasonic/matshita-uj272.htm